# How to set default country in Symfony3 form?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm using Symfony3 form. I have a`CountryType` in my Symfony form Builder. It's working correctly. But suppose the user belongs to a Company which is based in Spain. For that User I want to set the default country to be Spain and then show the rest of the countries. How can I do this in Symfony3.

I tried this but its not working.

```php
        $builder->add("country", CountryType::class, array(
            "label" => "Country",
            "required" => false,
            "preferred_choices" => array(
                "ES" => "Spain",
            ),
        ));
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Would the one out there who down voted please bother to explain what was wrong with the question that annoyed you?

Answer (score 6):

In this type `Country::class`, for use the preferred selection on array you should use:

```
->add('country', CountryType::class, [
    'preferred_choices' => ['DE'],
    'label' => 'address.form.country.label',
    'attr' => [
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'placeholder' => 'address.form.country.placeholder'
    ],
    'label_attr' => [
        'class' => 'col-sm-2 col-form-label'
    ],
])
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use the `data` option to set the default country.**

`preferred_choices` will put countries at the top of the list, but it will not set them as the default selected option.

This should be the way to go:

```
->add(
    'Country',
    CountryType::class,
    [
        'data'        => 'ES',
        'label'       => 'Country',
    ]
)
```

*(tested with Symfony 4 and 5)*